# C# StreamReader hangs with NetworkStream

Tags: c#, networking, stream, tcpclient, networkstream

So I've been messing with this code for awhile but couldn't figure out why it doesn't work
(I called the `Serialize` method and `Deserialize` on two different threads in a `while(true)` loop, the `Serialize` thread keeps sending while the `Deserialize` method gets stuck)

```
        public static void Serialize(NetworkStream stream, object obj)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            Console.WriteLine("Start Writing");
            writer.WriteLine(Deconstructor.Deconstruct(obj));
            Console.WriteLine("Done Writing");
        }

        public static object Deserialize(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            Console.WriteLine("Start reading");
            string objGraphData = reader.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done reading");
            return Constructor.Construct(objGraphData);
        }
```

OutPut:

```
Accepting new socket!
Start reading
Start Writing
Done Writing
Start Writing
Done Writing
Start Writing
Done Writing
Start Writing
Done Writing
Start Writing
Done Writing
Start Writing
Done Writing
Start Writing
Done Writing
```

Note: The streams work as well (I've tested them before with a BinaryFormatter) but now when I use StreamWriter/StreamReader instead of a BinaryFormatter the StreamReader part hangs on the reader.ReadLine() part

Comment: A networkstream will block when it is waiting for input. So: what is sending responses here? Has it sent a complete payload? Is the sender perhaps not flushing their buffers? Note: this approach to network IO doesn't scale well, but it should be *broadly* OK if your code is a client, not a server. For servers, you really need async (not thread-based) network code.

Comment: I made a class for server and client, they both use thread based network code since I couldn't find online any difference between thread and async based code.
right now I'm running a local test with only one client and server, the client is on one thread, calling the `Serialize` method with a simple `"hello"` string in `while(true)` loop and the server has a different thread which handles incoming client messages by calling the `Deserialize` method in a `while(true)` loop and prints the messages, I could send the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem here appears to be that you have a `StreamReader` (and writer) that is local to a single deserialize (or serialize) call. However, `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` are stateful types that have their own local buffers (because you can't push data back into a `Stream` if you've read too much, and you don't want to read individual `byte` values, for performance reasons - so it reads a chunk and then decodes it over multiple calls).

Because of this, once you've created a reader/writer over a `Stream`, you need to consider that reader/writer the single "owner" of that data. Effectively, only ever create one of each, and then don't talk directly to the stream again. Retain the reader/writer, and pass the *same* reader/writer to multiple successive serialize/deserialize calls.